# How to fetch a tag value from Test step response file (REST request's response) in SOAP UI

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

I am a newbie to SOAP UI, I need to fetch a tag value from Test step response file (REST request's response) and set it as testsuite property.

My Request file looks like;

```
<xdata created_by="XXXX" created_at="Wed Mar 16 08:45:39 EDT 2016" app="" profile="" app_version="" env="DEV" tran="" service="1234">
   <rows start_index="0">
      <row basketId="1234566" basketVersionId="11" basketName="ORDERS_1505" basketDescription="ORDERS" createdUserName="XXXX" updatedUserName="XXX" __errorMsg="{&quot;errors&quot;:[],&quot;success&quot;:true}" totalApprovedOrderCount="0"/>
   </rows>
</xdata>
```

I need to fetch `basketVersionId` attribute, please help.

Note: All the examples I read are dealing with Soap Response, property transfer using namespace and xpath. but that is not woking here I guess.

Comment: 1. there seems to be duplicated data, is that correct? 2. can you show which did not work as that will help better. 3. you were saying need to extract value from response and but you provided the request, would you like to provide response and tell which data to be extracted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*SOAPUI* converts practically all to *Xml*, so despite the fact that you've a *REST* service you can use anyway and *XPath* in the *property transfer testStep*.

The only difference is that in *property transfer* you've to select:

- `ResponseAsXml` as a property for the *REST* service with a *Json* response.
- `Response` as a property for a *SOAP* service with Xml response.

So you can use: `//*:row/@basketVersionId` as *XPath* to get your attribute value.

[image]

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks, the above xpath mentioned worked. So it was the xpath that i was giving wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: @SandyQAProffessional glad to help you `:)`